# Force call inner observable of switchMap if outer observable returned an error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, switchmap

My code:

```
    return this.userService.getPosition().pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.get('/places', { point: this.userService.coords });
      }),
    );
```

There can be a case, when the position cannot be retrieved (no https in Google Chrome, or user did not allowed).

In this case I still need to return `return this.get('/places', { point: this.userService.coords });`

Just in this call, `this.userService.coord` will be `null`.

Service code:

```
export class UserService {
  constructor() {}

  coords: Coordinates;

  getPosition(): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
        window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            this.coords = [position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude];
            observer.next(this.coords);
            observer.complete();
          },
          error => observer.error(error),
        );
      } else {
        this.coords = null;
        observer.error('Unsupported Browser');
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Currently - if the outer observable returned an error, the inner observable is not called(returned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [catchError](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) for this.

I don't really know the actual types you use, but it should look something like this.

Example:

```
return this.userService.getPosition().pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
      // We catched the error and are telling the pipeline to continue and
      // use the provided value.
      return of(this.userService.coords);
  }),
  switchMap(point => {
    // The following line will be reached regardless of any error that has occurred earlier in the pipeline.
    return this.get('/places', { point: point });
  }),
);
```

Comment: return this.userService.getPosition().pipe(
      switchMap(() => {
        return this.get('/places', { point: this.userService.coords });
      }),
      catchError(() => {
        return this.get('/places');
      }),
    );